# RxJava, Is it correct to clear disposable in subscribe?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

Usually, I call "disposable.clear()" on "onStop/onDestroy" function.

But today, I saw that my co-worker using the below code that calling the clear function in the subscribe function like:

```
val disposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

...

disposable.add(
    MyObservable()
        .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
        .observeOn(uiScheduler)
        .subscribe {

            // doSomething...

            disposable.clear // My question is here.
        }
)
```

Actually, it looks like working fine. But I don't know this code is correct or not...

Comment: Can you clarify what is `disposable`? Is it a list of disposables? If it is, then why would you clear all disaposables? Some of them might still be doing some work...

Comment: @Leo oh, yes, you're right... it may be clear all other things...

Answer (score 7):

When using RxJava in Android I normally "dispose" all disposables in `onDestroy`. It is safe enough to dispose of them in `onDestroy` because even if `onDestroy` never gets called you can safely assume that the system has killed your application process or the component that subscribed to the Observable.

The reason I never dispose a subscription in `onSuccess` or `onNext` is because for example, in the case of a `Flowable`...`onNext` can be emitted multiple times and it wouldn't make sense to dispose the subscription.

In fact, what I normally do is wrap the `CompositeDisposable` inside a `LifecycleObserver` so that it can be garbage-collected automatically based on a life cycle aware component. Here's an implementation that I use a lot...

```
class AutoDisposable : LifecycleObserver{

    lateinit var compositeDisposables: CompositeDisposable

    /**
     * Binds this observer to the specified life cycle object
     *
     * @param lifecycle The lifecycle object to bind to
     */
    fun bindTo(lifecycle: Lifecycle){
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
        compositeDisposables = CompositeDisposable()
    }

    /**
     * Registers a disposable that will be disposed when the bound lifecycle object is destroyed
     *
     * @param disposable The disposable to register
     */
    fun addDisposable(disposable: Disposable){

        if(::compositeDisposables.isInitialized){
            compositeDisposables.add(disposable)
        }
        else{
            throw Exception("This object must be bound to a lifecycle before registering a disposable")
        }
    }

    /**
     * Disposes all registered disposables
     */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy(){
        compositeDisposables.dispose()
    }

}
```

Then on an activity (or fragment) all you have to do is...

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    private val autoDisposables: AutoDisposable =
        AutoDisposable()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        autoDisposables.bindTo(lifecycle)
    }

    override fun onStart(){
        autoDisposables.add(
             MyObservable()
             .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
             .observeOn(uiScheduler)
             .subscribe {

                 // handle onNext
             }
        )
    }
}
```

Then you don't need to worry about, clearing or disposing your subscriptions. You can even go one step further and create a base activity or fragment that takes care of binding the `CompositeDisposable` and expose `protected` function to add disposables...

```
//on a base activity
protected fun registerDisposable(disposable: Disposable){
     autoDisposables.addDisposable(disposable)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in case of your co-worker only first value from `MyObservable` will be handled. It can be the point but also it can be an error.